# when use json_agg(json_build_object(.......)) ,how to ensure json_build_object return empty list

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

As title.
I write some SQL code like below :

```
SELECT p.id, 
       json_agg(
                json_build_object('id', sp.id)
                ) AS subProducts
  FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN sub_product sp
    ON sp.product_id = p.id
 GROUP BY p.id
```

as will be observed within

<kbd>[the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5nzHtfEb)</kbd>

but i get an issue, whenever `product id = 2`, then `subProducts` would be `[{"id" : null}]`

how to i ensure if nothing match, `subProducts` to be `[]`,
i have a idea, add column count(subPrdocts) as childNum,
and check childNum is 0.
But not grace.

thanks all.

Comment: Please provide some sample data of your tables and also the expected result.

Comment: [No row should return](https://dbfiddle.uk/tXXbc8Xr) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT p.id, 
       CASE WHEN jsonb_agg(sp.id) = '[null]' :: jsonb
         THEN '[]' :: jsonb 
         ELSE jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', sp.id)) 
       END AS subProducts
  FROM product p
  LEFT JOIN sub_product sp
    ON sp.product_id = p.id
 GROUP BY p.id
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iO4sUauH)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.id, 
       coalesce(json_agg(
            json_build_object('id', sp.id)
                ) filter (where sp.id is not null ), '[]')AS subProducts
  FROM product p
 left JOIN sub_product sp
    ON sp.product_id = p.id
 GROUP BY p.id
```

filter and coalesce are your friends